# How to register Azure AD multi-tenant app in another tenant (in which it wasn't created)

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

I created an Azure AD Multi-tenant app within my own tenant.

When I try and call the Admin consent endpoint from within another tenant, and signing in as another tenant's administrator, I get the error:

AADSTS700016: Application with identifier 'guid' was not found in the directory 'directory-id'. This can happen if the application has not been installed by the administrator of the tenant or consented to by any user in the tenant. You may have sent your authentication request to the wrong tenant.

How can another tenant provision and allow access to my multi-tenant app?

Answer (score 2):

I found this api to register the application in a different tenant.

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/<new-tenant-id>/oauth2/authorize?client_id=<client-id>&response_type=code&redirect_uri=<redirect-uri>
```

This will create a new enterprise application in the target tenant with the same client id and new object id.

Answer (score 0):

In this endpoint `GET https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/v2.0/adminconsent? client_id={client id}`, set `{tenant}` as the tenant id of another tenant. Set it as `common` should also work.

Make sure you are using the admin account of that tenant.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to register this app in other tenant. It will work for other tenant if it is already multi tenant and if it is using a  end point which supports multi tenant i.e.,`common`.

Pleace check your application manifest  has `"signInAudience": "AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount"` and `"accessTokenAcceptedVersion": 2` and Please update them if they are not same.